# Bug in find when using a zero int?

Tags: groovy, find, findall

I stumbled over this strange behaviour of the find function.

If I use "find" to find a 0 in an Integer Array it returns null even if there is 0 in the Array. If I try the same with "findall" or with another value like 2 it works as expected.

I stripped down my original code to produce this code snippet to reproduce the behaviour:

```
id = 0

class Node {
    int id = 1
    Set Nlinks = [0]
}

b1 = [new Node()].find{it.Nlinks.find{it2 -> it2 == id }}
b2 = [new Node()].find{it.Nlinks.findAll{it2 -> it2 == id }}

println(b1?.id + " " + b2?.id) // Output: null 1

id2 = 2

class Node2 {
    int id = 1
    Set Nlinks = [2]
}

b3 = [new Node2()].find{it.Nlinks.find{it2 -> it2 == id2 }}
b4 = [new Node2()].find{it.Nlinks.findAll{it2 -> it2 == id2 }}

println(b3?.id + " " + b4?.id) // Output: 1 1
```

​Is this behaviour expected and I'm missing something why this should be the way it behaves, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b1 = [new Node()].find{it.Nlinks.find{it2 -> it2 == id }}
```

the problem that `[0].find{it==0}` (the nested find) will find and return 0

means for the parent find expression evaluates to `0`

```
b1 = [new Node()].find{ 0 }
```

and `0` (zero) in groovy == false

so, just change your expression to this:

```
b1 = [new Node()].find{it.Nlinks.find{it2 -> it2 == id }!=null}
```

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find()

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#Groovy-Truth

Comment: ahhh now I get it I overlooked the implicit Integer to Boolean Groovy Magic in the outer find :)
The nested find returns an Integer and the outer find just evalutes the int as true unless it gets 0 which it evaluates as false. And the findAll works because it returns an array with one element and that's always true as well.
Thanks :)

Comment: don't forget Java under the hood:
b1 = [new Node()].find{it.Nlinks.contains(id)}